# How do I show a table's foreign key's in TimesTen?

Tags: database, oracle, timesten

How do I show a table's foreign key's in TimesTen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the indexes command on the table.

Ex.

```
indexes <table name>;
```

Answer (score 0):

command to check all the keys(pri/foreign) -> allindexes <table_name>